# Reactiveui, Conflict between System.Reactive and System.Reactive.Core

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactiveui, reactivex

I am using `reactiveui 10.5.7` in my wpf project `.net framework 4.6.1`.
i am trying to use the `reactiveui.validation 2.1.1` package, but after i installed the package i get a `TypeLoadException` that the `DispatcherScheduler` could not be loaded.
after reading on past issues on the subject, the reason for this error is because the `DispatcherScheduler` has moved to a  nuget package `rx-xaml`.
after installing the package, i get a conflict between the `System.Reactive` and `System.Reactive.Core`

how to fix this confilct?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are using PackageReference's if possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at nuget portal and `ReactiveUI.Validation` in version `2.1.1` depends on `ReactiveUI` in min version `13.1.1`. It looks like you are mixing incompatible libraries. With your current `ReactiveUI` version, you can use `ReactiveUI.Validation` in version `1.4.1`.